# Best way to log messages in a mobile-based social app

Tags: php, logging, concurrency

I'm developing the backend part of a social app. Clients are iOS/Android phones. The backend code is a PHP application that provides a REST API to clients.

I'm using a simple logging system, with several log levels and different log writers. The simpler writer is a FileWriter. All the log messages go to a log file that changes every day. The log files are not going to be used for analytical purposes, at least so far. Just record errors and user's important operations (database access, mainly)

I'm worried because, if the userbase grows quickly, I think that writing to a file is a kind of bottleneck, for 2 reasons:

- Disk writing overhead
- ¿Concurrency?

About the second point, I have a doubt. I'm sorry if the doubt is stupid: I'm using Apache with Prefork MPM. As far as different client's requests are handled using different processes, there're no concurrecy issues when two processes are trying to log messages to the same file. The OS (Ubuntu 11.10) handles this. Am I right?

Even in that case when I don't have to worry about concurrency writing to a file, is it a good idea? Isn't it too slow?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you open the file in append mode you are fine. Note that as long as you want persistent log files, they have to go to a file on disk at some point anyways. It makes absolutely no sense at all to use a DBMS, since that's simply another layer on top of the filesystem. As long as you don't open the file with caching disabled, the OS should take care of the I/O scheduling and write stuff off in bunches.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Just another quick question: Does it make sense to use only one log file/day? Is one log file per client a better approach?

Comment: @jorgeas80: File creation is more expensive than appending to an existing file, at least for most commonly used filesystems ;) If you are on linux and have control over the system, you should also look at setups with syslog, as this would keep the file handle open for you and do the file rotation + deletion of old logfiles.

Comment: And some people seem to use MongoDB for setups with many webservers to have a central logging facility